# How to include a variable inline

Tags: r, shiny

This seems like it should be easy, but I'd like to include a variable created in server.R in a sentence in UI.R.

For example, server.r:

```
averageSampleSize <- reactive({
    round(mean(sampleSizes()), 2)
})
```

In server.R I'd access this as averageSampleSize()

I want to display this in the UI within a sentence, e.g., "Given the settings, across simulations the average sample size required is XXX"

I tried stuff like including in Server.r:

```
output$averageSampleSize <- renderText({averageSampleSize()})
```

And in ui.R:

```
HTML("Given blah blah ...", textOutput("averageSampleSize")
```

No luck.  The last approach gives me cruft about how the variable is stored (list, etc.)

This seems really simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is `sampleSizes` here? a function defined in the UI ?

Comment: It's a reactively populated matrix of values defined in the server.  The averageSampleSize function just returns the mean of a matrix of sample sizes.  I want to be able to print just that mean within a string of text in the UI. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
library(shiny)

sampleSizes <- reactive(runif(100))
runApp(list(ui=bootstrapPage(
            textOutput("averageSampleSize")),
            server=function(input,output){
              averageSize <- reactive({
                round(mean(sampleSizes()), 2)
              })
               output$averageSampleSize <- renderText({paste('res=',averageSize())})
            }))
```